# add some note about release version with docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I created my own docker image and push it to the Docker repository.
But when I change my API version, I need to build a new docker image and push this new image to the repository too.

My question is how I can set some info about the API release version in the docker image?

Because in each version I change or upgrade my API. And I want to add some info about the new version because everybody pulls my docker image know changes in API.(like release note or read me file in git), so how I can add this?

Is it suitable to add this info to the docker image label?

If no how and where I can add this info?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have those information in the image.

`LABEL` needs to be used in the `Dockerfile` and it takes `key=value` pairs as arguments. This can be added after `FROM` directive.

For example the image is build with following softwares with different versions, here is how it is defined.

```
LABEL java.version=1.8 groovy.version=2.4 ant.version=1.9.4
```

So, similarly, you can add your api version.

Now the next question would be "how to see those details"?

Let us assume, an image `test` is pulled.

Use below command to see the information about the image.

`docker inspect test`

The above command will show all the metadata details in a json format. That will show the label as well along with many details.

```
"Labels": {
                "ant.version": "1.9.4",
                "groovy.version": "2.4",
                "java.version": "1.8"
            }
```

You may find more details about metadata of docker from [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/labels-custom-metadata/)

Apart from the above, [tag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/) the images appropriately.

`docker build -t IMAGE[:TAG]`

For eg: if app name is app1, and release verion is 1.1.0, this can be built using below command:

`docker build -t app1:1.1.0`

You may find similar examples in docker hub, say [tomcat](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/) to see sample naming conventions for images.

Comment: Is there any AWS or docker java API to get label details of imag?. I mean to get similar output as 'docker inspect test'. We are writting one app which will list all service, its images and image labels in a ECS conatiner. Now I am able to list services & its images using AWS apis 'com.amazonaws.services.ecs.AmazonECS'.  But not successful in reading image labels.

Comment: There are a multi-step solution to get the metadata for a particular image
Check this Stackoverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51062980/how-to-run-docker-inspect-to-obtain-image-meta-data-of-an-image-in-the-ecr-regis