# How to run Docker inspect to obtain image meta-data of an image in the ECR registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-ecs

I have the relevant access to the ECR registry however i am not able to get image meta data by running the Docker inspect command. I am trying with

```
docker inspect ecrregistryurl/dockerimage:imageversion
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**update**

If you are using recent version as mentioned by @muya_, you can use

```
aws ecr get-login-password | docker login -u AWS --password-stdin https://account-id.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

As mentioned by @Tarun I tried it but it's not giving me the same output as docker inspect. Here is the link from the documentation.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/Registries.html#registry_auth_http

```
#!/bin/bash
TOKEN=$(aws ecr get-authorization-token --output text --query authorizationData[].authorizationToken)
curl -i -H "Authorization: Basic $TOKEN" https://account_id.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v2/redis/manifests/latest
```

But check the output it's different from docker inspect.

```
Docker inspect image_name
```

This command will only inspect your local images instead of your Registry.

What you can do to get only relevant metadata that provides ECR.

```
aws ecr list-images --repository-name redis
```

It will give you an image tag and image id.

```
aws ecr describe-images --repository-name redis
```

This will give all the image and some more detail in this repo named redis.

> Now, For docker inspect first pull that images.

```
aws ecr get-login --no-include-email
```

run the output of this command. You will get a login using the token.

`docker pull account_id.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/redis:latest`

then run

```
docker pull account_id.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/redis:latest
```

You will get what you are looking for.

Or if you already running this image at some ec2 instance then run on that ec2 instance you will get the desired result.

```
docker inspect account_id.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/redis:latest
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/index.html

Comment: In more recent versions of the AWS CLI (tested on v2.9.17), the `get-login` command is deprecated.

Instead, it's recommended to use either: `aws ecr get-login-password` OR `aws ecr get-authorization-token`

Using the `get-login-password`, the generated value can then be used together with `docker login`, using `AWS` as the username:

`aws ecr get-login-password | docker login -u AWS --password-stdin https://account-id.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`

Answer (score 2):

You can't get information about the image like that, without having it downloaded. You need to pull the image first and then do an inspect

There is no command for the same. But there may be api available for the same. For dockerhub something like below works

```
curl \
    --silent \
    --header "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" \
    "http://$REGISTRY_ADDRESS/v2/$image/manifests/$tag" |
    jq -r '.config.digest'
```

See below article for more details

https://hackernoon.com/inspecting-docker-images-without-pulling-them-4de53d34a604

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is doable. You have to talk to the registry API directly though.

Although the pull-then-inspect approach may be slower and less efficient in the short term, it uses a stabler interface than the registry API so it may be more maintainable long-term to stick with pull-then-inspect.

```
import argparse
import json
import re
from pathlib import Path

import requests


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('image')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # TODO: this is quick and dirty, check what the actual requirements are. In
    # particular, can image contain /, or tag contain :, maybe with escapes?
    RE_DOCKER_VERSION = re.compile(r"(?P<host>[^/]+)/(?P<image>[^:]+):(?P<tag>[^:]*)")

    if (match := RE_DOCKER_VERSION.fullmatch(args.image)) is None:
        raise Exception(f"Couldn’t parse {args.image}")

    host, image, tag = match["host"], match["image"], match["tag"]

    # If you are definitely using AWS ECR, you should use boto3 to get the login
    # password directly. But this should work for any registry requiring auth,
    # not just for ECR.
    docker_config = json.loads(Path("~/.docker/config.json").expanduser().read_text())
    # If you b64decode the following value, you will see for ECR it is `AWS:xxxx…`
    auth = docker_config["auths"][host]["auth"]

    response = requests.get(
        f"https://{host}/v2/{image}/manifests/{tag}",
        headers={
            "Authorization": f"Basic {auth}",
            # https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#pulling-an-image says we
            # need to pass this, though ECR seems to ignore it.
            # https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/manifest-v2-2/ is supposed to
            # document the various manifest specs but I found it confusing.
            "Accept": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json"
        },
    )
    print('request 1 headers', response.headers)
    response.raise_for_status()
    print(response.text)
    manifest = response.json()
    digest = manifest["config"]["digest"]

    response = requests.get(
        f"https://{host}/v2/{image}/blobs/{digest}",
        headers={"Authorization": f"Basic {auth}"},
    )
    print('request 2 headers', response.headers)
    response.raise_for_status()
    print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For me, running

```
python script.py 503014274146.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/foo:latest
```

prints

```
request 1 headers {'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json', 'Docker-Distribution-Api-Version': 'registry/2.0', 'Sizes': '', 'Content-Length': '1329'}
{
   "schemaVersion": 2,
   "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
   "config": {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json",
      "size": 14512,
      "digest": "sha256:587ad9ba921cfa176f2e8fba84f7e78f1c38ef6ee147b5b2bd78ca46c66c973e"
   },
   "layers": [
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
         "size": 2683875,
         "digest": "sha256:f2fd7513120f741931f5aa402fb8270465150e0bcd16e0b398a7cb394c2b8593"
      },
      ⋮
   ]
}
```

That’s the information that the registry has about the image. If we
retrieve the config blob, we’ll get what `docker inspect` reports:

```
request 2 headers {'Last-Modified': 'Wed 24 Apr 2021 06:12:27 AM MDT', 'ETag': '"e5c907c0e39e44db69f5c361c8d46996-1"', 'x-amz-server-side-encryption': 'AES256', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream', 'Server': 'AmazonS3', 'Content-Length': '19351'}
{
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "config": {
    "Hostname": "",
    "Domainname": "",
    "User": "",
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": false,
    "AttachStderr": false,
    "Tty": false,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "StdinOnce": false,
    ⋮
```

There’s a lot more there that I’ve snipped off, like environment variables
and entry points and layer history too.